# Fragment loads multiple times on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, screen-orientation

When I change the orientation on the Emulator or Phone the fragment loads one additional time. If I were to rotate the device 3 times the fragment would load three times after the last rotation if I were to rotate the device 5 times it would load 5 times after the last rotation.

Main Activity

```
...
FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();

FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.main_container, fragmnet);
transaction.commit();
```

The only thing I have in the fragment are logs, nothing that should cause the fragment to load multiple times.
FragmentOne

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: ");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: ");
    }
```

Here is a copy of the log after one rotation, notice onCreateView is called multiple times with one orientation change.

```
2020-04-13 01:23:07.396 10857-10857/com.example.myapplication D/MYFragmentOne: onCreate: 
2020-04-13 01:23:07.396 10857-10857/com.example.myapplication D/MYFragmentOne: onCreate: 
2020-04-13 01:23:07.418 10857-10857/com.example.myapplication D/MYMainActivity: onCreate: 
2020-04-13 01:23:07.423 10857-10857/com.example.myapplication D/MYFragmentOne: onCreateView: 
2020-04-13 01:23:07.429 10857-10857/com.example.myapplication D/MYFragmentOne: onViewCreated: 
2020-04-13 01:23:07.429 10857-10857/com.example.myapplication D/MYFragmentOne: onCreateView: 
2020-04-13 01:23:07.431 10857-10857/com.example.myapplication D/MYFragmentOne: onViewCreated: 
2020-04-13 01:23:07.431 10857-10857/com.example.myapplication D/MYFragmentOne: onCreate: 
2020-04-13 01:23:07.431 10857-10857/com.example.myapplication D/MYFragmentOne: onCreateView: 
2020-04-13 01:23:07.433 10857-10857/com.example.myapplication D/MYFragmentOne: onViewCreated:



App details
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
minSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29
```

What would cause the fragment to load so many times with an orientation change?

Here is a link to my github
[Link](https://github.com/Shawn-Nichol/FragmentLoadError)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When activity orientation changes, it will call `onCreate()` again and the fragment you have put into it will be recreated as well. In this case, you should create fragment on activity's first load only. Then get the saved fragment instance on the next load. Use `tag` as the `Fragment` key.

```
private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "fragmentOne";

private Fragment fragment;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

    // savedInstanceState always null on activity's first load
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragment = new FragmentOne();
    } else {
        fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
    }

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG)
        .commit();
}
```

Comment: What is the point of running the `replace` transaction in the case where it's being recreated?  The Fragment is already there.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because this is "normal" behaviour of android lifecycle. When you turn around your phone/screen, orientation change is performed and result of it is recreation of activity. There are some solutions: First one is disabling orientation in manifest file, but this is probably not a solution you are looking for! Second one is checking if fragment is already added. You can make something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MYMainActivity";
    private FragmentOne fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
        if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new FragmentOne();

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();


        transaction.add(R.id.main_container, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case you will not be adding multiple fragments every time activity is recreated. Even better, you can check from fragment manager if fragment is already added from TAG, just add id  in transaction.add function and check it if exist!

Hope it helps you. But anyway, just must read how android lifecycle works for activity/fragments. 
Cheers

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding how this is a life cycle issue for fragments. The log I posted is from one orientation change, onCreateView is called three times and onCreate is called once. Booth these methods reside in the created state of fragment lifecycle, to me they should be called the same amount of times

Comment: As I said, it looks like you have so many different instances of fragments in manager. You are always adding fragments...If you know how to use profiler just check how many instances of fragments there are.

Comment: This answer is wrong. `fragment` will always be null in onCreate.