# How to use landscape and portrait layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-orientation, landscape-portrait

I have an activity and several fragments(they are called fragmentA and fragmentB).
Now fragmentA need to have both portrait and landscape layout. fragmentB have to keep portrait. The activity shows fragmentA in onCreate method.
I tryed this link:https://stackoverflow.com/a/53864286/15351040
Added following code in fragmentA.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        activity?.let {
            it.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR
        }
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }
override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        activity?.let {
            it.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED
        }
    }
```

And added following code in fragmentB.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    activity?.let {
        it.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
    }
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
}
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    activity?.let {
        it.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED
    }
}
```

But when I open fragmentB, fragmentA is opened again instead of fragmentB. Maybe the onCreate of activity is called when its requestOrientation is changed.
It works well when fragmentA is portrait, but not in landscape.

What should I do now?

Comment: Check the answers here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704009/setting-the-orientation-for-only-1-fragment-in-my-activity-while-the-rest-is-in

Comment: *"Maybe the onCreate of activity is called when its requestOrientation is changed"* It will be called, but it shouldn't be relaunching existing fragments.  Could you add your `onCreate`?  It likely has a bug.  This is _probably_ a duplicate of [Fragment loads multiple times on orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61183284/208273) or https://stackoverflow.com/a/42523923/208273, but it's impossible to say for sure without seeing the onCreate method.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks for your answer. I checked this link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61183284/208273, and solve my issue. Thanks again.

Comment: @RyanM : One more question. I just wanna rotate screen depending on its orientation without any reloading. In onCreate method of activity and onViewCreated method of fragmentA, there are so many initial code and I don't call them again. How can I do it?

Comment: Usually, what you want is to find some way to keep the loaded data (ViewModel is one).  If you _really_ don't want _any_ reloading, including View reinflation (for example, maybe you have a `WebView` that you need not to reload), and you don't have any size-dependent resources, and you know why it's usually a bad idea, the `configChanges` solution below will work for that.  But 99% of the time you want a ViewModel or some other way of retaining non-View-inflation work (`setRetainInstance(true)` on the Fragment is one way I like, but that will also result in View recreation and requires care).

Answer (score 1):

*Used this code, I hope this code usable*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PC)){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

*And attribute provide in manifest file, all screen*

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Answer (score -1):

Add configChanges tag with orientation value for activity in AndroidManifest.xml. For example:

```
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
```

Comment: 1) that's a bad idea, and will break things like screen-size-dependent resources on rotation, and 2) will absolutely not fix the root issue of relaunching fragment A.  This will, at _best_, mask the issue _sometimes_ while adding potential new problems.